# javascript import from '/folder' with index.js

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, webpack

I've noticed a few cases where I've seen something like the following:

```
// /reducers/reducer1.js
export default function reducer1(state = {}, action){
  // etc...
}
  
// /reducers/reducer2.js
export default function reducer2(state = {}, action){
  // etc...
}

// /reducers/index.js
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import reducer1 from './reducer1';
import reducer2 from './reducer2';

export default combineReducers({
  reducer1,
  reducer2
})
  
// /store.js
import masterReducer from './reducers';

export default function makeStore(){
  // etc...
}
```

Notice the last "file" where we call `import masterReducer from './reducers'` - A few people seem to believe this should import the `default export` from the index.js file.

Is this actually part of the specification? - my interpretation/question is that this is the result of many folks using WebPack v1 which translates `import` statements into CommonJS-style `requires` statements? Or will this break in WebPack v2 with "official" `import`/`export` support?

Comment: With webpack I'm not sure, but if you use babel it should transpile down to require statements

Comment: @SterlingArcher awesome name (one of my favorite shows) - are you sure that's the case if you use the [babel-preset-es2015-native-modules package](https://github.com/araphel/babel-preset-es2015-native-modules) (preset is 'es2015-native-modules' - the one recommended that you use to get support for tree shaking w/ `import` statements with WebPack 2)?

Comment: It's not compiled, but you can see some various export/import methods in my [games repo](https://github.com/RUJodan/SourceUndead). I'm still learning transpiling myself

Answer (score 83, accepted):

> Is this actually part of the specification?

No. How module identifiers (`'./reducers'` in your case) are resolved to the actual modules is left to the implementation of the module loader/bundler, it's not specificed by ES6. And it doesn't seem to be specified in [CommonJs](http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Modules) either.

This is just how node does it - when requiring a directory, it's `index.js` file will be used. Bundlers like [browserify](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify#packagejson) or [webpack](https://webpack.github.io/docs/resolving.html#resolving-an-absolute-path) followed this convention (for compat reasons).

Comment: Ah, I guess I misunderstood the question (should have looked at the title really). fwiw, webpack can be configured to resolve to other files than `index.js`.

Comment: @FelixKling: Ah, I didn't even look at that. Do you have a link, I could not find that config?

Comment: Hmm, after looking again, I guess that will come in webpack 2.0, not in the current version.