# ES 6 importing multiple default exports

Tags: ecmascript-6

I'm trying to understand the `import reducer from './reducers'` line at https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/examples/todos/src/index.js .

Within reducers folder there are 3 files which have `export default x` syntax. So, how does the `import` know which one to pick?

Logging out the reducer does seem to indicate that it is picking up the function produced by `combineReducers`. I see that `reducers/index.js` is using the other two default exports. But I'm still not clear how the import on line 1 intelligently picks up `default export todoApp` and not the other two default exports.

Comment: Looks related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35442174/javascript-import-from-folder-with-index-js

Comment: It's just a node js convention then?

Comment: I'd say more a _bundler_ (webpack, browserify, rollup, etc.) convention