# Why do I get an error when I do not (explicitly) specify importing an index file in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Why do I have to explicitly specify the index.js files from both router and store folders, in my project's entry file(main.js)? Without doing so, I get errors while importing the respective modules.

Below is the code in the project's entry file.

```
// main.js

import Vue from "vue"; 
import Vuetify from "vuetify"; 
import "vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css";

import App from "./App.vue"; 
import router from "./router";
//import router from "./router/index.js"; 
import store from "./store"; 
//import store from "./store/index.js"; 
import "./registerServiceWorker";

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

Vue.use(Vuetify);

new Vue({   
     router,   
     store,   
     render: h => h(App) 
}).$mount("#app");
```

Comment: I'm afraid there's nothing special with index.js files, just there are some tools that follow convention of loading proper index.js file if path doesn't match any module  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35442174/javascript-import-from-folder-with-index-js

Comment: I see. Thank you.