# Redux combineReducers with multiple files - making simple mistake

Tags: ecmascript-6, redux

I'm trying to set up a pattern for combining reducers from multiple files as per @gaearon's answer (https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/issues/609#issuecomment-133903294), but am making a simple mistake, and am unable to figure out what it is. Having some brain block on this one... :\

Getting the following error:

```
Store does not have a valid reducer. Make sure the argument passed to combineReducers is an object whose values are reducers.
```

### My Code:

**containers/score/reducers.js**

```
export const goals = (state = 0, action) =>
  action.type === types.UPDATE_GOALS ? action.payload : state

export const points = (state = 0, action) =>
  action.type === types.UPDATE_POINTS ? action.payload : state
```

**containers/time/reducers.js**

```
export const minutes = (state = 0, action) =>
  action.type === types.UPDATE_MINUTES ? action.payload : state

export const seconds = (state = 0, action) =>
  action.type === types.UPDATE_SECONDS ? action.payload : state
```

**containers/index.js**

```
import * as score from './score'
import * as time from './time'

export default Object.assign({}, score, time)
```

**store/configureStore.js**

```
import { createStore, combineReducers } from 'redux'
import reducers from '../containers'

const configureStore = initialState =>
  createStore(combineReducers(reducers), initialState)

export default configureStore
```

**components/provider.js**

```
import configureStore from '../store/configureStore'
const initialState = { minutes: 55 }
const store = configureStore(initialState)
```

On large code bases, it won't be enough to just directly import the reducers to the `configureStore` file. You have these enormous state trees that require hundreds of reducer files, and many reducers import other reducers from other files. Basically I'm asking how to manage a deeply nested state tree of reducers, and combine them one after another using `import` and `export` until they reach the root `combineReducers` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like score and time folders don't contain index.js files.

Try to add them or change your **containers/index.js** file:

```js
import * as score from './score/reducers.js'
import * as time from './time/reducers.js'
```

Comment: What should be be in the `./score/index.js` file? I've tried quite a lot of different things. Appreciate the help =)

Comment: Just take a look at your containers/index.js
It is a default file to import from a whole directory. Usually index.js reexports other modules. This link may be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35442174/javascript-import-from-folder-with-index-js

Comment: Got it. Looks like it's working. I'll double check in the morning, and if it's all hoopy, I'll mark this answer as correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If the object passed inside combineReducer is empty or invalid, you'll see that error.

I always structure my reducers this way,

1. I don't spin off separate export for every action, consolidate them into one export and manage with switch cases.
2. Each reducer's initialState is defined within the reducer for easy code management.

I've rewritten your code a bit:

**containers/score/reducers.js**

```
const initialState = {
  goals: 0,
  points: 0
};

const scoreReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case UPDATE_GOALS:
      return { ...state, goals: action.payload };
    case UPDATE_POINTS:
      return { ...state, points: action.payload };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
export default scoreReducer;
```

**containers/time/reducers.js**

```
const initialState = {
  minutes: 0,
  seconds: 0
};

const timeReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case UPDATE_MINUTES:
      return { ...state, minutes: action.payload };
    case UPDATE_SECONDS:
      return { ...state, seconds: action.payload };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
export default timeReducer;
```

**containers/index.js**

```
import score from './score';
import time from './time;
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  score,
  time
});

export default rootReducer;
```

And I don't complicate more after this - I just pass the provider and store to my main wrapper component after defining the combined reducers:

**src/index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import { Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import rootReducer from './container';
import history from './history';
import App from './App';

const store = createStore(
  rootReducer
);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={history}>
      <App />
    </Router>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

I really think structuring this way would solve your problem, please try.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but on large code bases, this likely won't be enough. You have enormous state trees that require hundreds of reducer files, so I'd like a pattern whereby I can go ahead and do that. This is especially essential if some reducers imported other reducers from other files. Basically I'm asking how to manage a deeply nested state tree of reducers.

Comment: Another problem with not exporting each reducer individually is that it makes it hard to compose reducers by importing other reducers.

Comment: When an action is dispatched, and if you are using combine reducers, all the reducers will be triggered. The appropriate state change happens in the tree where action.TYPE matches the dispatched action.TYPE. When you export everything individually, the number of reducers triggered will be a lot, I'm not sure how much memory toll it will take on your application.

Comment: I think you make an excellent point, but when you come to a massive codebase and there are many reducers that have been individually exported, you need to know how to handle them, hence my question. But in theory, I agree with you.

Comment: Also, @gaearon himself advises users to export reducers individually in the main Redux docs: https://redux.js.org/basics/reducers#note-for-es6-savvy-users

Comment: hmm, interesting, I'm going to shoot a question about memory consumed and performance in his repo. Thanks :)

Comment: Please post the link to the question here. It would be very interesting to read his response. Hope you have a great weekend! =)