# Internal server error: Failed to resolve import "./store" from "src\main.ts". Does the file exist?

Tags: vue.js, vite

I use vite in my application but I face an error when serve the application

> Internal server error: Failed to resolve import "./store" from "src\main.ts". Does the file exist?

The code is:

```
import store from "./store";
```

The error solved when I change the code to

```
import store from "@/store";
```

the same with the paths that starts with ../ like this

> Failed to resolve import "../utils/directives/ClickOutSide" from "src\views\Main.vue". Does the file exist?

My Project Structure:

```
-src
  -- store
     -- index.ts
  -- router
     -- index.ts
  -- main.ts
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [javascript import from '/folder' with index.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35442174/javascript-import-from-folder-with-index-js)

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem, The problem was  I wrote extensions: [".vue"] so
I changed it to extensions: [".vue", ".ts", ".js"]

Answer (score 0):

I this this is problem is for tsconfig.json file.
You need to add this to comilerOptions in tsconfig.json file. I think this is solution to your problem.

```
"paths": {
   "~/*": ["src/*"]
}
```